# Making real-time ordering dashboard with Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I recently found out about Firebase and it looks like something i wanted for my project. I'm trying to make a real-time html dashboard for ordering, yet i'm very much beginner at javascript so i was hoping someone could help me out.

I'm trying to make real-time dashboard that is blank, and updates div container when specific table in database in updated.[This is somewhat what i'm aiming for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhW6T.png)
I'm thinking it would work something like:

If database != null then create/show that container. Done button would just delete selected table in database.

But i don't know how to implement that using javascript. Any help/tutorial would be great, i searched a lot and didn't quite find what i needed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you gone through the Firebase Guide? A lot of what you need will be answered in it.  [Firebase Web Development](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/).  Go through that and then craft up some code and let us know where you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They answer you're looking for is beyond the scope of a single question. There are a number of great resources out there for learning how to set up your first web app using Firebase.

Take a look at their quickstart guide:

- [Firebase Quickstart Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.htmlhttps://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html)

Firebase also offers a number of examples:

- [Firebase's Examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/examples.html)

In addition, there are also a number of frameworks such as Angular.js, which add another layer of technology to learn, but provide useful features such as routing and data binding. I'd recommend Scotch.io's guide for creating an angular.js/firebase web app:

- [Scotch.io's Angular and Firebase Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-scheduling-app-using-angularjs-and-firebase)

Comment: While Scotch is amazing, that tutorial uses an outdated version of AngularFire. The docs for AngularFire are the single best place right now for learning about AF.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Looks like the tutorial was written for 0.8.8, while the current version of AngularFire is v1.1.3.